# How to find 1/more instances of [A-Z] or [0-9] without using +

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have two columns LN and HN which are alphanumeric.This is my data:

```
LN        HN
A1        B1
A100      B100
TN73OP1   TN73OP99
```

I need to write a  SQL query/function which will split the alpha and numeric part and compare if the alpha part of LN=alpha part of HN and the numeric part of LN=numeric part of HN.However,I only want it to compare data which has only 2 parts and is of the form (a+n) not a+n+a+n,i.e.,TN73OP1 which has 4 parts and so on.I am using SQL Server Management Studio

I tried including `patindex('[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+',LN )>0` but '+' is not being accepted as "1/more instances"

```
 SELECT AB.LN,AB.HN,
 CASE WHEN AB.FirstLN=AB.FirstHN THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS  FLAG1
 ,CASE WHEN AB.SecondLN=AB.SecondHN THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS  FLAG2
 FROM 
 (SELECT distinct LN
 ,SUBSTRING(LN,0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LN)) AS FirstLN
 ,SUBSTRING(LN, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LN),len(LN)) AS SecondLN,HN
 ,SUBSTRING(HN, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', HN)) AS FirstHN
 ,SUBSTRING(HN, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',HN),len(HN))AS SecondHN,
 FROM TABLE where PATINDEX('[A-Z]%[0-9]',LN)>0
 and PATINDEX('[A-Z]%[0-9]',HN)>0
 and LN<>HN and LN not like '%-%' and HN not like '%-%' 
 AND LN NOT LIKE '%-%' AND HN NOT LIKE '%-%')AB
```

Comment: And what results do you want?  What does "compare" mean?  Do you have examples of things that compare "correctly" and "incorrectly"?

Comment: compare means checking for "equality".e.g for A1 B1,i get flag1=No and flag2=Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> compare if the alpha part of LN=alpha part of HN and the numeric part of LN=numeric part of HN.However,I only want it to compare data which has only 2 parts

As far as I can tell from this description, you want to know if the values are valid and of the form alphas-digits, but not alphas-digits-alphas.

If so:

```
select (case when ln like '[A-Z]%[0-9]' and
                  ln not like '[A-Z]%[0-9]%[A-Z]' and
                  ln = hn
             then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end)
```

Comment: Hi Thanku for your suggestion..i modified it LN not like '[A-Z]%[0-9]%[A-Z]%[0-9] to meet my requirement